# How to achieve this for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataset

I'm trying to write a for-loop of a dataset. Just to make it simple, I'll write an example:

```
 Two variables, X and Y.
         X = 3, 6, 9
         Y = 4, 8, 12
```

I want to make a loop that does this:

```
   (Xi - Yi)^2, so first (3-4)^2, then 
   (6-8)^2 and so on.
```

Then, after that is done, multiply by this:

```
   ((1/2)/(n*(n-1))).
```

In this example, it would be:

```
     (3-4)^2 + (6-8)^2 + (9-12)^2 = 1 + 4 + 9 = 14
     1/2 / (3*(3-1)) = 0.5 / 6 = 0.0833.
     0.0833 * 14 = 1.166.

    result <- 0
    sum <- rep(NA, n)
        for (i in (1:n)) {
          for(j in (1:n)) {
          sum <- ((gathered$X[i] - gathered$X[j])^2)
     }
      }
```

Comment: If you have 2 vectors `X` and `Y` and you want to find the sum of squared distances,  then just do `sum((X-Y)^2)`

Answer (score 1):

Usually in R you can avoid `for` loops most of the times. For your case you can do

```
sum((X - Y)^2) * (1/2)/(length(X) * (length(X) - 1))
#[1] 1.166666667
```

---

However, as far as `for` loop is concerned you should be using a single loop since you want to access `X[i]` and `Y[i]` together.

```
sum <- 0
n <- 3
for (i in (1:n)) {
    sum <- sum + (X[i] - Y[i])^2
 }
sum * (1/2)/(n*(n-1))
#[1] 1.1667
```

**data**

```
X = c(3, 6, 9)
Y = c(4, 8, 12)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!
But, in this case, I need to use a for-loop, hence why I asked for it.
Also, in the dataset I'm working with, it's 5000 X's with variable numbers and 5000 Y's with variable numbers.
So it's basicly how to get (X1-Y1)^2 + (X2-Y2)^2 and so on for all the 5000 numbers, then multiply with the mentioned ((1/2)/(n*(n-1)))

Comment: @arziona even if you have 5000 `X`s and 5000 `Y`s this should still work assuming `length` of both `X` and `Y` is the same and you don't have any `NA`s in that case you need to add `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum`. Can you test this on your real data once and confirm?

Comment: @ronak_shah this didn't work, don't really know why, as I'm pretty new to R. There are no NA's in either X or Y.

Comment: @arziona What do you mean by it didn't work? Did it give you any error message? Any warning?

Comment: @ronak_shah No, well the code worked so to say, but I know what the answer is, and I didn't get that from the code provided by you.

Comment: @ronak_shah 
result <- 0 
for(i in (1:10)) { 
for(j in (1:10)) { 
print(c(i,j)) 
result <- result + 1 
} } 
print(result
consider this, hopefully the format is fine

Comment: I am not sure what the `for` loop is doing. What answer did you get? What was your expected answer?

Comment: @ronak_shah form the code you gave me I got 0.04, the answer is 205

Comment: strange...can you update your post with `dput(head(X))` and `dput(head(Y))` ?

Comment: @ronah_shah I am not allowed to use that command, sadly.. there's alot of restrictions to this, so it's hard to explain, and even harder to help, sadly :(
The comment with two for-loops from 20 min ago is supposed to be a hint on how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

How about this, i think `outer` is fit to your problem.

### CASE 1 ( X-Y )

```
sum(diag(outer(X,Y,function(X,Y)(X-Y)^2))) *
 (1/2)/(length(X) * (length(X) - 1))
1.166667
```

### CASE 2 ( all X and Y calculation )

```
sum(outer(X,Y,function(X,Y)(X-Y)^2)) *
(1/2)/(length(X) * (length(X) - 1))
15.5
```